# What is the best practice, using const in render or state directly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm new to react, please help me understand the best practice.

Should I use const in render or state directly?

Below is the sample code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

    class VehicleDetail extends Component{
        constructor(props){
           super(props);
           this.state = {vehicle: [] };
        }

    componentDidMount() {

            axios.get(`/getDetails/${this.props.match.params.id}`)
                .then(response => {
                    this.setState({ vehicle : response.data.vehicle });
                });
        }

    render() {

        const vehicle = this.state.vehicle;

        return(
            <div className="col-12 col-md-5 car-price-detail">
                <h3>{vehicle.title}</h3>
                <h5><span>Mileage:</span> {vehicle.mileage}</h5>
                <h5><span>Color:</span> {vehicle.exterior_color}</h5>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

---

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

    class VehicleDetail extends Component{
        constructor(props){
           super(props);
           this.state = {vehicle: [] };
        }

    componentDidMount() {

            axios.get(`/getDetails/${this.props.match.params.id}`)
                .then(response => {
                    this.setState({ vehicle : response.data.vehicle });
                });
        }

    render() {

        return(
            <div className="col-12 col-md-5 car-price-detail">
                <h3>{this.state.vehicle.title}</h3>
                <h5><span>Mileage:</span> {this.state.vehicle.mileage}</h5>
                <h5><span>Color:</span> {this.state.vehicle.exterior_color}</h5>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ESLINT suggest you to use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) your variables:

```
const { vehicle } = this.state;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use destructuring as ESLINT suggest. With destructuring, your every line will look less.

Also, cosider the situation,

```
return (
    <div className="col-12 col-md-5 car-price-detail">
        <h3>{this.state.vehicle.title}</h3>
        <h5><span>Mileage:</span> {this.state.vehicle.mileage}</h5>
        <h5><span>Color:</span> {this.state.vehicle.exterior_color}</h5>
    </div>
);
```

You are directly using the state variable here. There could have been many more lines as well. If sometime in your future, you have to change the state variable `vehicle`, You will need to change every single line wherever you are using it. Which is a bad code practicing. Also, that will affect your code maintenance as well. That's why we are using destructuring

```
const { vehicle } = this.state;

return (
    <div className="col-12 col-md-5 car-price-detail">
        <h3>{vehicle.title}</h3>
        <h5><span>Mileage:</span> {vehicle.mileage}</h5>
        <h5><span>Color:</span> {vehicle.exterior_color}</h5>
    </div>
);
```

With this code, you will have only a single line of change if there happens such a situation. That's a good practice. These are some reasons I know. If anyone else knows anything more, please chip in. Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it doesnt matter. Use method that you feel suits you. I personally use destructuring variables in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no best practice, this is a matter of style. Notice that since props and state properties may have same names, excessive destructuring may result in naming collisions and lead to inconsistencies:

```
render() {
    const { vehicle } = this.state;
    const { vehicle: vehicleProp }  = this.props;
    ...
```

Keep objects for reference is less ambiguous, this results in more verbose but easier to understand code because the use of `state` and `props` objects tells something about how a component works:

```
const { state, props } = this;
...
{state.vehicle || props.vehicle}
...
```

While `this.state` and `this.props` are excessive in JSX expressions (also inconsistent with functional components).